# Search array of object with filter and keyword

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, filter

I have an array, filter and keyword.
i want to search in that array using filter and keyword, with result array of object too. Just like first array.

```
var data = [
  {email: "usera@gmail.com",nama:"User A", Level:"Super Admin"},
  {email: "userb@gmail.com",nama:"User B", Level:"Super Admin"},
  {email: "userc@gmail.com",nama:"User C", Level:"Standart"},
  {email: "userd@gmail.com",nama:"User D", Level:"Standart"},
  {email: "usere@gmail.com",nama:"User E", Level:"Admin"},
  {email: "userf@gmail.com",nama:"User F", Level:"Standart"}
];
var filter = "Level";
var keyword = "Standart";

//--------Search


console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function which takes a callback and filters accordingly. Per the documentation:

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

The callback, which is the provided function, takes three arguments. From the documentation:

> **`callback`**
>
> Function is a predicate, to test each element of the array. Return true to keep the element, false otherwise, taking three arguments:
>
> `element`
>
> The current element being processed in the array.
>
> `index`
>
> The index of the current element being processed in the array.
>
> `array`
>
> The array filter was called upon.

We may use `element` to check the current element and test if it should be filtered or not, like so:

```js
var data = [
  {email: "usera@gmail.com",nama:"User A", Level:"Super Admin"},
  {email: "userb@gmail.com",nama:"User B", Level:"Super Admin"},
  {email: "userc@gmail.com",nama:"User C", Level:"Standart"},
  {email: "userd@gmail.com",nama:"User D", Level:"Standart"},
  {email: "usere@gmail.com",nama:"User E", Level:"Admin"},
  {email: "userf@gmail.com",nama:"User F", Level:"Standart"}
];
var filter = "Level";
var keyword = "Standart";

var filteredData = data.filter(function(obj) {
 return obj[filter] === keyword;
});

console.log(filteredData);
```

Here, we use a callback (the test) that checks if the current element (`obj`)'s property specified in `filter` is strictly equal to `keyword`. If it passes, it is kept, and thus all objects with property `Level` with vale `Standart` are kept. You can also shorten this with [ES6 arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
var filteredData = data.filter((obj) => obj[filter] === keyword);
```

This is just shorthand for the above. It is effectively the same, returning true or false based on if the current element's `Level` property is strictly equal to `keyword`.

Comment: how if the keyword is a wildcard ?
in mysql using %keyword%
can i using /^keyword/ ?

Comment: @RenandattaRooziq That's really out of my expertise. If you mean a regex, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test). It can be applied like so: `/regex/.test(obj[filter])`.

Comment: yeah, i mean regex

Comment: @RenandattaRooziq Then yes. Instead of `obj[filter] === keyword` do `/^keyword/.test(obj[filter])`

Comment: i'm sorry, but it doesn't work, here my script https://jsfiddle.net/renandatta/yhdyb5bg/5/

Comment: @RenandattaRooziq What is that you are trying to filter out? What's the desired end result?

Comment: i want to search that array like in mysql, in mysql i using WHERE LIKE "%keyword%". i have Level : "Standart", if i search "Stand", i want result all element with level Standart

Comment: @RenandattaRooziq Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/yhdyb5bg/11/ - use `JSON.stringify` as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function to filter through the array with a custome function:

```
var data = [
  {email: "usera@gmail.com",nama:"User A", Level:"Super Admin"},
  {email: "userb@gmail.com",nama:"User B", Level:"Super Admin"},
  {email: "userc@gmail.com",nama:"User C", Level:"Standart"},
  {email: "userd@gmail.com",nama:"User D", Level:"Standart"},
  {email: "usere@gmail.com",nama:"User E", Level:"Admin"},
  {email: "userf@gmail.com",nama:"User F", Level:"Standart"}
];
var filter = "Level";
var keyword = "Standart";

//--------Search
var filtered_data = data.filter(function(item) {
    return item[filter] == keyword
})

console.log(filtered_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `filter()` function to filter out the elements based on a condition like this:

```
> var data = [
  {email: "usera@gmail.com",nama:"User A", Level:"Super Admin"},
  {email: "userb@gmail.com",nama:"User B", Level:"Super Admin"},
  {email: "userc@gmail.com",nama:"User C", Level:"Standart"},
  {email: "userd@gmail.com",nama:"User D", Level:"Standart"},
  {email: "usere@gmail.com",nama:"User E", Level:"Admin"},
  {email: "userf@gmail.com",nama:"User F", Level:"Standart"}
];
> var newData=data.filter(function(x) { return x.Level == 'Standart'})
> console.log(JSON.stringify(newData))
[{"email":"userc@gmail.com","nama":"User C","Level":"Standart"},{"email":"userd@gmail.com","nama":"User D","Level":"Standart"},{"email":"userf@gmail.com","nama":"User F","Level":"Standart"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the array filter method to accomplish your goal here.

```js
var data = [{
  email: "usera@gmail.com",
  nama: "User A",
  Level: "Super Admin"
}, {
  email: "userb@gmail.com",
  nama: "User B",
  Level: "Super Admin"
}, {
  email: "userc@gmail.com",
  nama: "User C",
  Level: "Standart"
}, {
  email: "userd@gmail.com",
  nama: "User D",
  Level: "Standart"
}, {
  email: "usere@gmail.com",
  nama: "User E",
  Level: "Admin"
}, {
  email: "userf@gmail.com",
  nama: "User F",
  Level: "Standart"
}];
var filter = "Level";
var keyword = "Admin";

var filteredArray = data.filter((item) => item[filter] === keyword);
console.log(filteredArray);
```