# Keyword search of object returning array

Tags: javascript, object, higher-order-functions

Beginning coder here taking a js course. I'm almost done with a higher order function lesson, but am stuck. I have an object containing 250 countries with different info. Example:

```
const countries = [
    {
      name: 'Afghanistan',
      capital: 'Kabul',
      languages: ['Pashto', 'Uzbek', 'Turkmen'],
      population: 27657145,
      flag: 
'https://restcountries.eu/data/afg.svg',
      currency: 'Afghan afghani'
    },
    {
      name: 'Åland Islands',
      capital: 'Mariehamn',
      languages: ['Swedish'],
      population: 28875,
      flag: 
'https://restcountries.eu/data/ala.svg',
      currency: 'Euro'
    }, etc.
```

I'm asked to write a function that searches each country's name and returns an array of only the countries meeting the keyword criteria. I'm stumped and feel very lost. Here's what I have:

```
const keys = Object.keys(countries)
function categorizeCountries(keyword) {
    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        let country = countries.name
        if (country.includes(keyword)) {
            console.log(countries.filter((country) 
=> country.includes(keyword)))
     } else {
        console.log('Country not found')
        }
    }
    return country
}
categorizeCountries('land')
scategorizeCountries('stan')
```

I'm sure the issue is in my conditional statement, but I don't know how else to go about this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Search array of object with filter and keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40336345/search-array-of-object-with-filter-and-keyword)

Answer (score 0):

This is a short snippet demonstrating how to do it with `.filter()` and `.includes()` (@IvanaMurray made a good point regarding the application of `.toLowerCase()` for the strings to be compared, which I have left out here for simplicity):

```js
const countries = [
{
  name: 'Afghanistan',
  capital: 'Kabul',
  languages: ['Pashto', 'Uzbek', 'Turkmen'],
  population: 27657145,
  flag: 
'https://restcountries.eu/data/afg.svg',
  currency: 'Afghan afghani'
},
{
  name: 'Åland Islands',
  capital: 'Mariehamn',
  languages: ['Swedish'],
  population: 28875,
  flag: 
'https://restcountries.eu/data/ala.svg',
  currency: 'Euro'
}];

["land","stan","an"].forEach(s=>
 console.log(countries.filter(c=>
  c.name.includes(s)))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `Object.keys` you only get the keys of the array. In your case just `"0"` and `"1"`. What you want is the values. And then it's quite easy to sort using the filter prototype.

```js
const countries = [
    {
      name: 'Afghanistan',
      capital: 'Kabul',
      languages: ['Pashto', 'Uzbek', 'Turkmen'],
      population: 27657145,
      flag: 
'https://restcountries.eu/data/afg.svg',
      currency: 'Afghan afghani'
    },
    {
      name: 'Åland Islands',
      capital: 'Mariehamn',
      languages: ['Swedish'],
      population: 28875,
      flag: 
'https://restcountries.eu/data/ala.svg',
      currency: 'Euro'
    }];

const countriesArray = Object.values(countries);
function categorizeCountries(keyword) {
    
    console.log(countriesArray.filter(country => country.name.toLowerCase().includes(keyword.toLowerCase())))
}
categorizeCountries('af')
```

Answer (score 0):

you are looping incorrectly through countries (you don't need `Object.keys` and you omitted usage of `i` also you have to accamulate your result in array)

```
function categorizeCountries(keyword) {
    const result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
        let { name } = countries[i];
        if (name.includes(keyword)) {
            console.log(name);
            result.push(name);
     } else {
        console.log('Country not found')
     }
    }
    return result;
}
```